# Eloquent How to Omit Row if value is empty

Tags: database, laravel, mapping, eloquent

I have three tables.

1. Customer
2. Product
3. Reviews

I have used Eloquent for mapping these tables.

For example,

In Review Model for customer details I have function like

```
public function customer(){
      return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'customer_id');
}
```

and for product details I have function like

```
public function product(){
      return $this->belongsTo('Product', 'product_id');
}
```

Now Querying reviews model like

```
Review::all()->with(array('customer', 'product'))->get()
```

returns the values. That is fine. But, if any customer is deleted, then the value for the row is just empty. Instead I need to omit that row. How to do this in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Perhaps adding the where clause to your approach works too.

```
$allReviews = Review::all()
   ->join('customers', 'reviews.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
   ->join('products', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
   ->where('customers.firstname','!=','') // given that there is a column firstname in table customers
   ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `has()` to filter for models that have at least one related model:

```
Review::with('customer', 'product')->has('customer')->get();
```